# .htaccess to add subdomain to permalinks (dev server to staging)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, development-environment, subdirectory, staging

I have developed a static site that works great when on my local server: `mysite.dev`

However, in my staging server, I have it going into a subdirectory:
`sites.domainname.com/mysite`

While it works on my local server (MAMP Pro), when I FTP the files to the `/mysite` directory, a link that should be `sites.domainname.com/mysite/about/index.php` is actually `sites.domainname.com/about/index.php` (completely leaving out the subdirectory folder "`mysite`")

How can I fix this using .htaccess in the `mysite` folder?

Comment: When you upload the files is the .htaccess file included?

Comment: I have the .htaccess on the staging server only, not on my local dev server.

Comment: It will be helpful to know what's inside that .htaccess file.

Comment: Nothing currently is in the .htaccess. I've tried tons of things from googling, but none have worked, so it is a completely blank .htaccess file.

Comment: Maybe the uploaded files have relative links that don't match the directory structure of the web site and don't include the /`mysite` folder in the path. ¿Have you checked that?

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve in the .htaccess. It works fine on my dev server, so the relative links work fine there. It is just not working properly on dev because of the subfolder.

Comment: In this case maybe the best approach is to use a mod_alias directive in the .htaccess file in **root directory** For example: `Redirect 301 / http://sites.domainname.com/mysite/` I am not sure about the syntax but that's the idea.